# upgrading postgresql 9.1.2 (9.1.3) -> 9.2.1 via homebrew

Tags: upgrade, uninstallation, homebrew, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

In a round of upgrades I ended up (literally, it was the last upgrade left) updating postgresql via homebrew. It installed PostgreSQL 9.2.1.

I couldn't make it run:

```
Dart:~ Arta$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
server starting
Dart:~ Arta$ psql -d postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Not understanding what exactly I was doing I tried the 'start', 'stop', 'load on login', etc. command lines from the Caveats, but postgresql wouldn't start, so I uninstalled the 9.2.1 version.

Now, I cannot run my original brew install (9.1.2, 9.1.3). Advise on how I can launch my original postgres would be great. I'm stranded.

Also:

```
$ which psql 
/usr/bin/psql
```

This shouldn't be, and it certainly was not the case before the update - I installed postgres via homebrew on a clean Mac (it runs OS X 10.7.5 now). No clue how to get out of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're can't run postgres 9.2 on old db (/usr/local/var/postgres), that was created by version 9.1